# System halts in event loop for a big for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a service in which for loop is iterating about 1 million times and the event loop engaged until all the iterations completes.

Is there any method to run for loop in background without halting the event loop?

Comment: any specific reason to run a loop 1 million times ? that is too harsh on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why there is a for loop running for 1 million times, my suggestion would be to use Distributed delayed jobs like [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) or [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) and if you have any exprience with Ruby on Rails then [node-resque](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque) might sound familiar.